# How should we tag questions that aren't about any one game in particular?

Tags: discussion, tags

Here is the situation: someone made a question, and added WAY too many tags. I wanted to retag it with something general (general, multiple-games) but we don't really have that many 'general' tags, so I turned to Meta.

If a question like this pops up, should I close it, or re-tag it with a more general tag?

Comment: It would depend on the situation. If the question is asking about a series and then tags each individual game, then it should be re-tagged as `{game}-series`. If it's a wide variety of unrelated games, then it should probably be closed as too broad. If it's the same question for different (but related) games, then it should be two different questions since the answer could vary

Comment: Is there a particular situation at hand here or is this a hypothetical?

Comment: [Oh I found it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384783/how-can-i-prevent-myself-from-getting-stressed-during-gameplay-in-video-games)

Comment: I don't think it really matters as the seemingly only example of this happening is off-topic

Comment: A tag called [gaming] would be a bit too broad.